# How browsers react to attributes they don't know

Tags: html, cross-browser, tags

Straight forward:

if I do:

```
<div id = "thisid" class = "a lot of classes" mom = "your momma" sexynesslevel = "itsover9000">
```

I know that chrome and firefox (my testing browsers), just ignore the attributes, but is there any browsers that could have problems with them? or delete them?

Comment: On a side note, the popular Angular uses non-standard attributes with the `ng-` prefix. Any browser that was ever supported by Angular should be fine at least. Some browsers may strip out unrecognized properties of style attributes though.

Answer (score 2):

No. Very early on the HTML spec described this scenario and explicitly states that unrecognized attributes are to be ignored by a browser. Many javascript frameworks actually rely on the use of non-standard attributes like this.

https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec.txt

> Undeclared attributes are treated
>       similarly. The entire attribute specification of an unknown
>       attribute (i.e., the unknown attribute and its value, if any)
>       should be ignored

Comment: Just what I was looking for ! Thanks. A formal specification of what have to happen. I'm doing exactly that, a javascript that rely on non-standard attributes, so any browser following specifications is fine.